# Flooring issue in a house we just sold, new owners want us to foot the bill for the repair

Tags: repair, flooring, structural, canada

We recently sold our 36 years old house to two brothers in their 20s.  Two weeks later, we get an email from them telling us that the varnish of the floor in the bedrooms was not done properly and that they would need to sand them and re-apply varnish and they think it's our responsibility to pay the bill (around $2k).  They say they couldn't see this issue during their visit since it's mostly under the beds and furniture.

Since this does not seem to us like anything more than an aesthetic imperfection, we replied that we wouldn't pay.  Shortly after, they sent another email where they now say that the floor was not installed properly, that it's not straight because some doors don't open fully (there's one door that gets stuck on the floor when opened really wide, more than you'd ever need to get in or out) and that a specialist was recommending that they redo the whole floor.  They are ok to just sand and varnish though, as long as we pay for it.

We again replied that it's unlikely that the floor was installed improperly since the house inspectors had not noticed anything (It might be worth noting that the offer they made and that we accepted had no condition about the house being inspected first, they instead relied on an inspection that had been requested by a previous prospective buyer who ended up not being granted the mortgage).  We lived in that house for over 9 years with no issue with the floor, which had been installed prior to us moving in.

They are now threatening legal action claiming that this is a hidden defect.  To qualify as such, the issue must mean that the owner does not have the full and normal use or enjoyment of their property and that it is not apparent and cannot be noticed by a simple examination.

Does the issue as they describe it sound plausible?
Could the issue be instead with the door frames?
Would the issue as they describe it meet the conditions for a hidden defect?

This whole thing smells like a shakedown to me.

Comment: Without pictures it is hard to tell.  Off hand being under stuff, the rest of the floor might just be faded from sunlight, and under beds not faded.  Peeling varnish, gouges  or stains will be different matter.

Comment: They had the opportunity to look, or to have an inspection ahead of the sale, and they did not take it. Presumably the inspection that was done did not note it. Houses are bought and sold "as is" unless the contract says otherwise.

Comment: A hidden defect would be something major affecting the structure or safety.  Most surface finishes will fall under normal wear and tear.

Comment: The fools relied on a 3rd party home inspection that they got for free, so their beef with the inspector is not actionable. This is a shakedown, plain and simple. Tell them they own the house now, you demand that they cease further contact with you, and if they persist, you will file a criminal complaint for harassment. Then stick to it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a legal/contract issue, not a DIY/Home Improvement question. It _might_ fit on [law.se], but you'd have to consult their rules to be sure.

Comment: @FreeMan The legal context probably overshadows the question(s) I was hoping to get answers for from this site. Mainly as to how plausible it would be that a flooring issue which went unnoticed for over 9 years could suddenly become so dire.  I'm good to close though, if anything, the answers/comments reinforced my suspicion of this being a shakedown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not your responsibility to fix. Stop talking to them until you have, at a minimum, talked with your real estate agent or the attorney you used for your sale. You're just making them think there might be a possibility that their BS strategy will work. If it were me, I would respond with 'I never had issues with that floor. Good luck with your repairs.' Then if they kept bugging me, I'd block them.

Unless you actively tried to deceive them, you are fine. This sounds like people who didn't realize that a 36 year old used house has some imperfections, and they're trying to avoid having to take any responsibility for the thing they just bought.

The time to find this sort of minor issue and negotiate it is before you buy the house. After they bought the house, congratulations, they own it.

BTW: this is somewhat off topic for the DIY SE. If you really want solid answers, you should go ask on the [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was debating whether to post on LAW or here.  I guess I want opinions from people with house building experience on whether this sounds like a plausible issue or not

Comment: The issue they describe could absolutely be happening, sure. That's not relevant though. Don't let them suck you in to thinking it is. They are doing the classic tactic where they start with something reasonable-ish sounding, then escalate it to 'this is totally wrong', then do you the 'nice' thing of offering to settle for what they originally complained about. Stop talking to them. If they want to actually sue you for it, deal with it then. They won't. Otherwise they're just trying to get you to give them money that you are under no obligation to provide.

Comment: Oh and if the door rubs because a floating floor was installed, you usually plane the bottom of the door to fix it. You don't reinstall the floor. But really, don't get sucked in to the details, because they don't matter. They needed to do their due diligence. They didn't. It's not your responsibility at all. You didn't set out to deceive them or to misrepresent the house. You're fine.

Answer (score 2):

Whether what they claim is true or not - ask them if they've ever heard the term **'caveat emptor'** [buyer beware.]

This means it was **their responsibility** to discover issues - usually by employing a qualified surveyor/inspector - *before* purchase.

They only have any case at all if you can be proven to have deliberately misled them. Their failure to spot it, or make accusations about it afterwards, is a day late & a dollar short.

If you need a lawyer's advice… ask a lawyer, not the interwebz at large.